# Disk Space not freed up even after deleting keyspace from cassandra db and compaction

Tags: cassandra

I created a keyspace and a table(columnfamily) within it.
Let's say `"ks.cf"`

After entering few hundred thousand rows in the columnfamily `cf`, I saw the disk usage using `df -h`.

Then, I dropped the keyspace using the command `DROP KEYSPACE ks` from `cqlsh`.

After dropping also, the disk usage `remains the same`. I also did `nodetool compact`, but no luck.

Can anyone help me out in configuring these things so that disk usage gets freed up after deleting the data/rows ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are just trying to delete rows, then you need to let the deletion step go through the usual delete cycle(delete_row->tombstone_creation->compaction_actually_deletes_the_row).

Now if you completely want to get rid of your keyspace, check your cassandra data folder(it should be specified in your yaml file). In my case it is "/mnt/cassandra/data/". In this folder there is a subfolder for each keyspace(i.e. ks ). You can just completely delete the folder related to your keyspace.

If you want to keep the folder around, it is good to know that cassandra creates a snapshot of your keyspace before dropping it. Basically a backup of all of your data. You can just go into 'ks' folder, and find the snapshots subdirectory. Go into the snapshots subdirectory and delete the snapshot related to your keyspace drop.

Comment: Yup !! It maintains snapshots which can be deleted manually. But still I see    the same disk space using df -h, but it is not growing when I push data into cassandra again. Maybe OS or Cassandra does some kind of caching or disk space management which I do not know.

Comment: Remember, for all cassandra writes, data is first held in memory until cassandra decides it is time to flush it to the disk in form of an SStable. You can manually flush it to disk via 'nodetool flush <keyspace>'.

Comment: Oh ok !! then there must be some config params which decides when to flush and how much data to flush..What are those config params? Will I find it in Cassandra official documentation?

Comment: Yes - memtable_total_space_in_mb ... here is the link in the official docs: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__memtable_total_space_in_mb

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I will see what I can do with these params in my application.

Answer (score 19):

Ran into this problem recently.  After dropping a table a snapshot is made.  This snapshot will allow you to roll this back if this was not intended.  If you do however want that harddrive space back you need to run:

`nodetool -h localhost -p 7199 clearsnapshot`

on the appropriate nodes.  Additionally you can turn snapshots off with `auto_snapshot: false` in your cassandra.yml.

edit: spelling/grammar

Comment: I used the same method but still there are empty directories left even after clearsnapshot. My guess is that it is safe to delete those. Anyone?

Comment: @gubble Yeah, i ended up manually removing them due to OCD.  Make suer the hashes line up if you have similarly named tables.

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra does not clear snapshots automatically when your are dropping a table or keyspace. if you enabled auto_snapshot in the cassandra.yaml then every time when you drop a table or keyspace Cassandra will capture a snapshot of that table. This snapshot will help you to rollback this table data if this was not done by mistake. If you do clear those table data from disk then you need to run below clearsnapshot command to free space.

nodetool -u XXXX -pw XXXXX clearsnapshot -t snapshotname

You can disable this auto_snapshot feature any time in cassandra.yaml.

Comment: I think this is a better answer to the OP question

Answer (score 1):

`nodetool cleanup` removes *all* data from disk that is not needed there any more, i.e. data that the node is not responsible for. (`clearsnapshot` will clear all snapshots, that may be not what you want.)

Comment: `nodetool cleanup` triggers special type of compaction that is applied to all or specific keyspaces/tables. If the table is dropped, then Cassandra doesn't care about it anymore, so no compaction will happen...

Answer (score 1):

The `nodetool` command can be used to clean up *all* unused (i.e. previously dropped) tables snapshots in one go (here issued inside a running `bitnami/cassandra:4.0` docker container):

```
$ nodetool --username <redacted> --password <redacted> clearsnapshot --all
Requested clearing snapshot(s) for [all keyspaces] with [all snapshots]
```

Evidence: space used by old tables snapshots in the `dicts` keyspace:

a) before the cleanup:

```
$ sudo du -sch /home/<host_user>/cassandra_data/cassandra/data/data/<keyspace_name>/
134G    /home/<redacted>/cassandra_data/cassandra/data/data/dicts/
134G    total
```

b) after the cleanup:

```
$ sudo du -sch /home/<host_user>/cassandra_data/cassandra/data/data/<keyspace_name>/
4.0K    /home/<redacted>/cassandra_data/cassandra/data/data/dicts/
4.0K    total
```

Note: the accepted answer missed the `--all` switch (and the need to log in), but it still deserves to be upvoted.